# Is there any way to check printer action and operation?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Any way to show "printed success" message in website after printing completed in printing machine? I need to implement this function in my client website using either .Net, jQuery, javascript.

**CONDITION:** The data displayed in grid with "print" option when user click the "print" the default browser print dialog box appear. The message should be displayed only when printing completed in printing machine.

**My doubt:** Is any way to check printer action and operation using either .Net, jQuery, javascript like we checking mouse and keyboard events ?

Comment: Do not keep posting the same question over and over again.

Comment: I thought my 1st question didn't give clear information. so i posted again with full information.